# CSS tile layout using floats

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have 7 tiles that i want to layout like the following image using CSS and floats[image]

However i can't get the last 2 tiles to 'float' correctly. 
Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPeRqO?editors=1100

Here is my code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="sixth">6th</div>
  <div class="fourth">fourth</div>
  <div class="second">second</div>
  <div class="seventh">seventh</div>
  <div class="fifth">fifth</div>
  <div class="third">third</div>
</div>
```

And my CSS

```
.container {max-width:1220px; max-height:370px;}
div{margin-right:10px;}
.first{  float:left;  width:550px;  height:370px;  background-color:#d7df52;  }
.second{  float:left;  width:210px;  height:190px;  background-color:#51a279;  }
.third{  float:left;  width:210px;  height:215px;  background-color:#d17466;  }
.fourth{  float:right;  width:210px;  height:190px;  background-color:#d17466;  }
.fifth{  float:right;  width:210px;  height:180px;  background-color:#d17466;  }
.sixth{  float:right;  width:210px;  height:170px;  background-color:#d17466;  }
.seventh{  float:right;  width:210px;  height:200px;  background-color:#d17466;  }
```

Comment: You cannot accomplish this type of layout with `floats` alone. If you are already giving things static widths and heights why not just `absolute` position everything? It would make more sense then all the left and right float toggling and unordered `div` naming

Comment: I disagree, you can achieve this layout with floats however it will require some thought and a slight hack. do you want this to be a responsive layout or something just for desktop use? Please explain a little more what your goal is and we can help for sure.

Comment: @Dan Ya you could use just floats but you need extra HTML markup. Plus a hacky float solution might be a pain to maintain (add or removing elements in the future). I like layout that make sense

Comment: Yes this layout needs to be responsive and needs to work on mobile devices.The absolute layout causes issues when implemented on different platforms

Comment: @user2016193 I would recommend something using flex for your layout. Like what Paulie_D posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flebox can do that...in order too:

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/obPPoe?editors=1100)

The relevant part

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 1230px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height: 430px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  }

.container div {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}


.first {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 370px;
  background-color: #d7df52;
}

.second {
   width: 210px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #51a279;
}

.third {
  width: 210px;
  height: 215px;
  background-color: #d17466;
}

.fourth {
  width: 210px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #d17466;
}

.fifth {
  width: 210px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #d17466;
}

.sixth {
  width: 210px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #d17466;
}

.seventh {
  width: 210px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #d17466;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="second">second</div>
  <div class="third">third</div>
  <div class="fourth">fourth</div>
  <div class="fifth">fifth</div>
  <div class="sixth">sixth</div>  
  <div class="seventh">seventh</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS3 Flexbox?
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
You can align the items with flex-start and flex-end for the correct position - maybe this could work:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   .first {
      align-items: flex-start;
   }
  //and so on...
}
```